# How to format a double with leading zeroes and rounded decimals

Tags: c++, string, formatting, fmt

Is there an elegant way to format a double as a string with a fixed amount of digits before the decimal point (padded with leading zeroes), but showing decimals only a needed and with a maximum precision?

For example, with a fixed 3 digits before, and up to 2 digits after the decimal point:

```
// desired:
1.00000 -> "001"
1.10000 -> "001.1"
1.12345 -> "001.12"

// not:
1.10000 -> "0001.1" // too many leading zeroes
1.12345 -> "1.1235" // too few leading zeroes, too many digits after the decimal point
```

Additional constraints:

- The decimals need to be actually rounded, not padded with spaces
- Negative numbers are not a concern, they are filtered out before this point
- The input is in the range [0.0, 180.0]

We looked into printf, stringstream, boost::format and [fmtlib](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), but none of them seem to offer specific controls on the amount of digits *before* the decimal point. The standard way to control this is by adjusting field width and precision, but this doesn't quite seem to offer the granularity we need.

The most "elegant" solution we found so far is the following (where `123.1f` is the input value):

```
boost::trim_right_copy_if(fmt::format("{:06.2f}", 123.1f), boost::is_any_of("0"))
```

But I can't help thinking there's got to be a more elegant/robust solution for this.

---

For context, we have a GUI that displays latitude/longitude coordinates. Our customer has asked us to pad with leading zeroes, but reduce digits as much as possible. This is a compromise between reducing unnecessary information, while also preventing confusion as much as possible. e.g.:

```
W135°2'2.3344" -> W135°02'02.33"
W135°22.3344"  -> W135°00'22.33"
W135°2'3"      -> W135°02'03"
W135°22'2.999" -> W135°22'03"
W1°35"         -> W001°00'35"
W1°35'         -> W001°35'00"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using a solution that prints the whole coordinate at once, since I had loads of rounding errors processing degrees/minutes/seconds separately (e.g. 2.0° being printed as 1°60'). It was inspired by vitaut's solution to format the integer and decimal parts as separate strings:

```
// value is the input in decimal degrees (e.g. 77° 20' = 77.3333333)
// deg_width controls if degrees are printed with 2 (latitude) or 3 (longitude) digits
std::string formatDMS (double value, size_t deg_width) 
{
    std::string res;
    static const int SECONDS_DECIMAL_PLACES = 2; // amount of decimals to print seconds with

    // Convert everything to int, to get rid of pesky floating-point errors
    static const int ONE_SECOND = std::pow (10, SECONDS_DECIMAL_PLACES);    // e.g. 1 second = 100 * 0.01 (seconds with 2 decimals)
    static const int ONE_MINUTE = 60 * ONE_SECOND;  // e.g. 1 minute = 6000 * 0.01 (seconds with 2 decimals)
    static const int ONE_DEGREE = 60 * ONE_MINUTE;  // e.g. 1 minute = 360000 * 0.01 (seconds with 2 decimals)

    const int value_incs = std::lround (value * ONE_DEGREE);
    const int degrees = value_incs / ONE_DEGREE;
    const int deg_rem = value_incs % ONE_DEGREE;
    const int minutes = deg_rem / ONE_MINUTE;
    const int min_rem = deg_rem % ONE_MINUTE;
    const int seconds = min_rem / ONE_SECOND;
    const int sec_rem = min_rem % ONE_SECOND;
    const double decimals = static_cast<double>(sec_rem) / ONE_SECOND;
    const auto decimals_string =
    fmt::format ("{:.{}g}", decimals, SECONDS_DECIMAL_PLACES).substr (1);

    const auto fmtstring = "{:0{}d}° {:02d}\' {:02d}{}\"";
    res += fmt::format (fmtstring, degrees, deg_width, minutes, seconds, decimals_string);
    return res;
}

formatDMS(77.0, 2);         // 77°00'00"
formatDMS(77.033333333, 2); // 77°02'00"
formatDMS(77.049722222, 2); // 77°02'59"
formatDMS(77.049888889, 2); // 77°02'59.6"
formatDMS(77.999999999, 2); // 78°00'00"
formatDMS(7.0, 3);          // 007°00'00"
formatDMS(7.2, 3);          // 007°12'00"
formatDMS(7.203333333, 3);  // 007°12'12"
formatDMS(7.203366667, 3);  // 007°12'12.12"
formatDMS(7.999999999, 3);  // 008°00'00"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void
output(double d)
{
    std::stringstream pre;
    pre << static_cast<long int>(d);

    std::stringstream post;
    post << d-static_cast<long int>(d);

    int pre_digits = pre.str().length();
    int post_digits = post.str().length() - pre_digits;
    int width = pre_digits + post_digits + 2;

    if (post_digits > 2) {
        post_digits = 2;
        width = pre_digits + post_digits + 3;
    }

    std::cout << std::setfill('0')
            << std::setprecision(pre_digits + post_digits)
            << std::setw(width)
            << d
            << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    output(1.00000);
    output(1.10000);
    output(1.12345);

    return 0;
}
```

Which results in:

```
001
001.1
001.12
```

**UPDATE**: Made some edits to make sure the outputs were the same as what you were looking for.

Comment: Cool, and all that without external libraries. `1.12345` still needs to be rounded to `"001.12"`, but that's just a small tweak. I'm hoping for a nice one-liner though, let's see if anyone finds one.

Comment: I've been testing your latest update in our software, and found a problem with input >= 10. Try the following input values: `123.12345`, `123.00000`, `76.54321`, `76.00000`

Comment: Yeah.... my guess is there is some tweaking that would be needed to handle all cases... I only really tested the cases you provided. I don't think a general one-liner is possible with the standard library

Answer (score 1):

You can do it pretty easily with {fmt} or other library by formatting integral and fractional parts separately:

```cpp
#include <cmath>
#include <fmt/core.h>

std::string double_to_string(double value) {
  double integral = 0;
  double fractional = std::modf(value, &integral);
  return fmt::format("{:03.0f}", integral) +
         fmt::format("{:.2g}", fractional).substr(1);
}

double_to_string(1.00000); // -> "001"
double_to_string(1.10000); // -> "001.1"
double_to_string(1.12345); // -> "001.12"
```

This might need minor tweaks to support negative values.

Also you could use `fmt::memory_buffer` and `fmt::format_to` to avoid string allocations.

Your solution is pretty robust too because the output of `fmt::format` is stable and not affected by locale.

Comment: Short but efficient, I like it. I still had trouble with values like 11.999999 though (would be shown as 11.0), so I ended up using a different solution to get around this; however, it is heavily inspired by yours. Thanks!